# jQuery logic filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, logic

I have a list of post links that have tags inside an inner div.  A user selects from three different lists to filter the posts.

Essentially what I want to achieve is front end filtering based on the contents of the three lists the user picks.

I want the logic to basically be like this: `IF post-tags-list has 1+ item from list1 AND has 1+ item from list2 AND has 1+ item from list3, THEN keep the post`

Below is what I have as a start, but the way it currently is I would need a large amount of `IF` statements to account for if somebody doesn't select anything from one of the lists.  I know it'd probably be easier with switches, but I'm not entirely sure if my logic is even correct.

```
$(".post-link").each(function(index){
    //Get all the post's terms from its hidden tag div and store in an array
    var terms = $(this).find(".tags").attr('class').split(" ");
    //Cut off the first two items ('hidden' and 'tags')
    terms.splice(0,2);
    //If interests is set
    if(typeof interests[0] != 'undefined'){
        var found = 0;
        var keep = false;
        //For each of the selected interests...
        $.each(interests, function(index, value){
            //For each of the posts terms
            $.each(terms, function(index2, value2){
                //If the posts has a selected interest, keep it
                if(value == value2){ keep=true;}
            });
        });
        //After all that, if we couldn't find anything...
        if(keep!=true){
            //Hide the post (.post-link)
            $(this).hide();
        }
    }
    //THE ABOVE ONLY ACCOUNTS FOR IF SOMETHING IS SELECTED FOR THE FIRST LIST
    //I'M NOT SURE HOW I WOULD IMPLEMENT THIS ACROSS TWO OTHER LISTS
});
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution to my problem.  Essentially for each post, I set a show variable and set it to true (we want to show the post unless proven otherwise).  So I check if each of my three lists have something in them, if I do, then do a foreach inside a foreach to check if one of my post terms matches my selected item.  If there is, keep show=true, else its false.  Do this for the other two lists.  After these three checks, if show is still true, it HAS to have at least one item from each three fields (if three are applicable), if it's false, hide the post.

Here's the code:

```
$(".post-link").each(function(index){
    var show = true;

    //Get all the post's terms from its hidden tag div and store in an array
    var terms = $(this).find(".tags").attr('class').split(" ");
    //Cut off the first two items ('hidden' and 'tags')
    terms.splice(0,2);

    //If interests is set
    if(typeof interests[0] != 'undefined'){
        var found = 0;
        $.each(interests, function(index, value){
            $.each(terms, function(index2, value2){
                if(value == value2){ found++; }
            });
        });
        if(found < 1){
            show = false;
        }
    }

    //If type is set
    if(typeof type[0] != 'undefined'){
        var found = 0;
        $.each(type, function(index, value){
            $.each(terms, function(index2, value2){
                if(value == value2){ found++; }
            });
        });
        if(found < 1){
            show = false;
        }
    }

    //If experience is set
    if(typeof experience[0] != 'undefined'){
        var found = 0;
        $.each(experience, function(index, value){
            $.each(terms, function(index2, value2){
                if(value == value2){ found++; }
            });
        });
        if(found < 1){
            show = false;
        }
    }

    if(!show){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```